# Retrieving data from Parse.com takes too many times

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

I create an apps in parse.com and add 5 rows with 7 column in a class.Now,When I retrieve data from there with objectid, its take about 10 sec to get all the data. Here is my code:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"QUestion"];

    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[arrId objectAtIndex:i] block:^(PFObject *Q_1, NSError *error)
     {

         [arrQuestion addObject:Q_1[@"Ques"]];
         [arrAns1 addObject:Q_1[@"Ans1"]];
         [arrAns2 addObject:Q_1[@"Ans1"]];
         [arrAns3 addObject:Q_1[@"Ans1"]];
         [arrAns4 addObject:Q_1[@"Ans1"]];
          //.........

         NSLog(@"%@",arrQuestion);

     }];


}
```

pls help

Comment: Why do you do this in loop?

Comment: I have arrId, which contains all 5 objectid

Answer (score 0):

I would use find method with condition objectId `whereIn` = array of IDs.

This way you could get array of objects in a single network request.

Comment: sir,can you please explain?